# Mysql formula to work out how many points they have according to value in a column

Tags: php, mysql

I have done this the long and hard way but I know it can be done quicker and easier ;)

If I have a column called 'puzzle_level' I wish to have 10 points for each record that is puzzle_level=5, 25 points for each record where puzzle_level=6 and 50 points if puzzle_level=7;

Quick edit, I actually need a varialbe total in PHP, so it would be $total_points = $sql_formula

Comment: $POINTS=array(5=>10,6=>25); etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply do it with a conditional `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT 
    points + 
    CASE puzzle_level 
        WHEN 5 THEN 10 
        WHEN 6 THEN 25 
        WHEN 7 THEN 50 
    END AS totalpoints
FROM your_table
```

This adds an amount of points based on the puzzle_level to the total point amount in the `points` column.

Then, simply reference the `'totalpoints'` column in PHP.

Comment: Sorry but I'm actually after a variable total in PHP.  So $total_points = $sql_formula

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE `table`
SET `points` =
  IF `puzzle_level` = 5 THEN 10
    ELSEIF `puzzle_level` = 6 THEN 25
    ELSEIF `puzzle_level` = 7 THEN 50
  END IF
```